# Error "Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined" binding n-api module

Tags: vue.js, cmake, electron, n-api

I wrote a c++ module using [n-api](https://nodejs.org/api/n-api.html), compiled it with [cmake-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cmake-js) and now want to use it in my `electron-vue` app. If I use the module in a project without `electron-vue` it works. But when I try to use it in my `electron-vue` app I'm always getting this error:

```
 App threw an error during load
 TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined
      at Function.getFileName (D:\temp\test2\node_modules\bindings\bindings.js:178:16)
      at bindings (D:\temp\test2\node_modules\bindings\bindings.js:82:48)
      at eval (webpack:///./src/main/index.js?:28:67)
      at Module../src/main/index.js (D:\temp\test2\dist\electron\main.js:3822:1)
      at __webpack_require__ (D:\temp\test2\dist\electron\main.js:21:30)
      at eval (webpack:///./src/main/index.dev.js?:11:1)
      at Object../src/main/index.dev.js (D:\temp\test2\dist\electron\main.js:3810:1)
      at __webpack_require__ (D:\temp\test2\dist\electron\main.js:21:30)
      at eval (webpack:///multi_./src/main/index.dev.js_./src/main/index.js?:1:1)
      at Object.0 (D:\temp\test2\dist\electron\main.js:3880:1)
```

I'm using [bindings](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bindings) like so:

```
const colorBalance = require('bindings')('colorBalance');
```

I have tried to define my module as external according to [this](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder/issues/3696#issuecomment-509341561) but it didn't solve the problem:

```
// vue.config.js
module.exports = {
  pluginOptions: {
    electronBuilder: {
      externals: ['NameOfMyModule']
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Most probably you are trying to apply method 'indexOf' to variable which isn't defined yet. Take a look at docs https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf . Check if your variable is defined somewhere and it should be an array type.

Comment: Thanks, but the error comes from the node-bindings module and not from my own code. The error happens here bindings.js:178:16 (first at... in the error message) seems that fileName is undefined but I don't know how to solve this. Everything works fine in my test app without electron-vue.

Comment: It's looks like this is the same issue as here https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-bindings/issues/54

Comment: To be true: I don't understand if it is the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

In the meantime I've tried to import the module without `bindings`:

```
const colorBalance = require('../../build/Release/colorBalance.node');
```

Then I getting a new error:

```
Error: Cannot open D:\temp\test2\build\Release\colorBalance.node: Error: Module did not self-register.
      at Object.eval (webpack:///./build/Release/colorBalance.node?:1:155)
      at eval (webpack:///./build/Release/colorBalance.node?:2:30)
      at Object../build/Release/colorBalance.node (D:\temp\test2\dist\electron\main.js:97:1)
      at __webpack_require__ (D:\temp\test2\dist\electron\main.js:21:30)
      at eval (webpack:///./src/main/index.js?:28:20)
      at Module../src/main/index.js (D:\temp\test2\dist\electron\main.js:3833:1)
      at __webpack_require__ (D:\temp\test2\dist\electron\main.js:21:30)
      at eval (webpack:///./src/main/index.dev.js?:11:1)
      at Object../src/main/index.dev.js (D:\temp\test2\dist\electron\main.js:3821:1)
      at __webpack_require__ (D:\temp\test2\dist\electron\main.js:21:30)
```

I've rebuild electron using `electron-rebuild`. I've read about `win_delay_load_hook` [here](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/using-native-node-modules) and tried [this](https://github.com/cmake-js/cmake-js/issues/153) but the error doesn't disappear.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved my problem by changing the build chain from `cmake` to `gyp`. Compiling with `gyp` everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

@grobotor, regarding the self-register issue. Please see these resources :)

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/41283828
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/55177338

TLDR; I discovered my issue was due to this in the bindings.gyp

```
"sources": [ ],
```

This was causing the error "Error: Module did not self-register" when I was attempting to run autotests on Linux (as module is only built for mac)
https://github.com/codebytere/node-mac-permissions/issues/23

Regarding your original issue, I don't think electronBuilder externals is where that property should be since it's a packager. The `externals` needs to configure the bundler, such as with webpack's `externals`

Example of my configuration:

```
// Bundle all deps when building dist (except native modules), otherwise streamline development by just using local node_modules dir
externals: packDistributable ? [{
    permissions: "node-mac-permissions"
}] : [nodeExternals()],
```